# Adding data to the JWT refresh response

Tags: symfony, jwt, token, refresh, response

I use [LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle) and [JWTRefreshTokenBundle](https://github.com/markitosgv/JWTRefreshTokenBundle) with Symfony.
I try to add custom data on jwt_refresh_token response but i can't. I know we can do it without refresh token using [this](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2-data-customization.md#eventsauthentication_success---adding-public-data-to-the-jwt-response), but i think jwt_refresh_token_bundle override this response.

Anyone have an idea how to add custom data on jwt_refresh_token response ? To get a response like this by example :

```
token: "..."
refresh_token: "..."
user: "..."
```

Thanks by advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my solution [here](https://github.com/markitosgv/JWTRefreshTokenBundle/issues/67#issuecomment-337896720). But in addition to this manipulation of priority, i need to remove the folowing code :

```
    if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        return;
    }
```